# the scroll bar does not respond when assigning a value to scollTop (mobile only)

Tags: javascript

#### Problem Description

xx.scrollTop = xx is used in web API IntersectionObserver. After testing, it is completely normal on pc, and the scroll bar scrolls. However, on the mobile terminal (Android), although the assignment is successful, there is no scrolling.

#### Environment

no frame used

#### Code

```js
    this.selectedItem = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.isIntersecting) {
        // -------------------------------------this line
          this.yearScrollEl.scrollTop = 100
        }
      })
    }, {
      root: this.element.querySelector('.timePicker-wheel'),
      threshold: [0.6]
    })

    this.element.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((item) => {
      this.selectedItem.observe(item)
    })
```

#### Tried method

After adding a timer, the scroll bar is in effect:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.yearScrollEl.scrollTop = 100
},300)
```

But I don’t know the principle, if anyone can tell me the answer I will be very grateful